# Take the max of each day and sum mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 columns (`server varchar(20)`,  `transactions int(20)`,  `timestamp timestamp(0)`). There are multiple servers that log the transactions they get hit with over the course of a day. I want to write a query that sums the max transaction (per day) over the course of a multiple months and display a column for each month.

I believe I am close with the following broken query, but the problem is that it takes the max value of the whole month rather than getting the sum of the max of each day in the month.

```
SELECT IFNULL(server, 'TOTAL') AS Server,
       FORMAT(SUM(MAX(CASE WHEN DATE(TIMESTAMP) >= DATE('2014-10-01')
                  AND DATE(TIMESTAMP) < DATE('2014-11-01') THEN transactions ELSE 0 END),0)) AS 'Oct - 2014',
       FORMAT(SUM(MAX(CASE WHEN DATE(TIMESTAMP) >= DATE('2014-11-01')
                  AND DATE(TIMESTAMP) < DATE('2014-12-01') THEN transactions ELSE 0 END),0)) AS 'Nov - 2014',
       FORMAT(SUM(MAX(CASE WHEN DATE(TIMESTAMP) >= DATE('2014-12-01')
                  AND DATE(TIMESTAMP) < DATE('2015-01-01') THEN transactions ELSE 0 END),0)) AS 'Dec - 2014',
       '' AS 'Total'
FROM transactionstable
GROUP BY Server WITH ROLLUP;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want nested group bys, first by date and server to get the maximum and then by server to get the `sum()`.  A sketch of the query is:

```
select server, sum(maxt)
from (select date(timestamp) as d, server, max(transactions) as maxt
      from transactiontable tt
      where date(timestamp) between @TIMESTAMP1 and @TIMESTAMP2
      group by date(timestamp), server
     ) t
group by server;
```

EDIT:

Just do a conditional aggregation in the outer query:

```
select server, sum(maxt),
       sum(case when year(timestamp) = 2014 and month(timestamp) = 11 then maxt end) as sum_201411,
       sum(case when year(timestamp) = 2014 and month(timestamp) = 12 then maxt end) as sum_201412,
       sum(case when year(timestamp) = 2015 and month(timestamp) = 1 then maxt end) as sum_201501
from (select date(timestamp) as d, server, max(transactions) as maxt
      from transactiontable tt
      where date(timestamp) between @TIMESTAMP1 and @TIMESTAMP2
      group by date(timestamp), server
     ) t
group by server;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I want to have a separate column for each month to show the sum(max) of say the last 3 months. Your answer would only show the sum(max) for one specific range right?

Comment: @ttran . . . It can easily be adapted to have multiple columns, if you want.

Comment: This worked! I was skeptical about it being able to get the max of each day within a month and summing it up for each server. Thanks so much for your time.